# bounds on binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, functions, binomial-coefficients

Do the standard upper bounds on the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ still work well if $k=f(n)$  (by standard i mean for example $(\frac{en}{k})^{k}$ and $\frac{n^{k}}{k!}$)? In particular if $k=o(n)$. If these do not work that well can anyone point me in the direction of some useful bounds in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If $k=f(n)$ then the inequality $${n\choose f(n)}\leq \frac{n^{f(n)}}{f(n)!} $$ holds obviously and this implies $${n\choose f(n)}\leq \left(e\frac{n}{f(n)}\right)^k. $$
 If $f(n)\leq \frac{n}{2}$ then $k\leq f(n)$ implies ${n \choose k}\leq{n\choose f(n)}$. Since in this case $$\frac{n \choose k}{n \choose f(n)}\leq \frac{k!}{f(n)!}$$ $k=o(f(n))$ implies ${n\choose k}=o\left((e\frac{n}{f(n)})^{f(n)}\right)$.